# Removing commas when using whitespace tokenizer

Tags: elasticsearch

When using the whitespace tokenizer a text like "there, he is." would be split to 
"there," "he" and "is.". Naturally I would want to remove those punctuation that the standard tokenizer would had removed automatically.

My questions are:

1. How to trim those punctuation marks? (in elasticsearch setting, like adding another token filter or charfilter)
2. I need to use the whitespace tokenizer mainly because I don't want hyphenated words to be splited. Is there a way I can achieve this while still using the standard tokenizer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the char filter to remove the the ",". [Char Filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html

I̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶s̶e̶t̶u̶p̶ ̶a̶ ̶s̶n̶i̶p̶p̶e̶t̶ ̶=̶>̶ ̶h̶t̶t̶p̶:̶/̶/̶e̶s̶.̶s̶u̶b̶i̶t̶o̶l̶a̶b̶s̶.̶c̶o̶m̶/̶#̶/̶t̶e̶s̶t̶r̶/̶m̶6̶m̶f̶b̶4̶a̶h̶i̶m̶8̶6̶w̶2̶9̶

Answer (score -3):

you can use split() to remove all punctuation marks

```
String str ="there, he is.";
String[] ss = str.split("[ ,.]");   
for (String string : ss) {
System.out.println(string);
}
```

try this
this will help u

Comment: This wasn't a java question.